# Place Your Bets 3 , last of the series

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-sequence, probability

> A harder sequence to figure out...

### What are the next 4 cards, including suits?

[image: Find My Pattern]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is:

> 3 of Hearts 6 of spades 10 of clubs 7 of diamonds

reason:

> Add 3 over one suit, add 4 over one suit, minus 3 over one suit, minus
>  4 over one suit then restart

Comment: I can see I really need to step up my game regarding puzzle creating... lol

Comment: Had me thinking lol

Comment: I don’t get it. This is the sequence given in the question. “Add 3 over one suit”? 7+3 will be 10. 3+3 is 6. How are you getting the 3 of hearts again?

Comment: I started the pattern at the 3 of hearts so you subtract 4 after the 7 of diamonds